# How can I apply to the differential form of Gauss' Law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

I'm trying to learn Maxwell's equations but I got stuck. I couldn't understand the usage of the differential form of the Gauss' law. How can it be applied to questions? For example, let's say there is a plate sizes of 10 cm X 5 cm and has a charge of 1 C. To calculate the electric field on the point ***a***, can I use ∇⋅E=ρ/ϵ0? (The distance between plate and point ***a*** is much smaller than the size of the plate)

Comment: You can sometimes solve the differential equation and apply some boundary conditions to get the electric field. However, usually the integral form is used to calculate electric fields. The differential form is easier to use when you know the electric field and you want to find out what charge distribution causes it.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck Can you give me an example like what boundary conditions you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, physical problems are solved by the integral form of Gauss's law

$$
\iint_S\,\mathbf{D}\bullet d\mathbf{s} = \rho
$$

and the application of [Gaussian Surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_surface) if the geometry of the problem allows.
This quickly lets you work with discontinuities of the medium, adjusting the limits of integration.

The differential form, fits differentials set field values. Apply this to objects, involves integrating the proposed differential field for a given geometry. Hence the practical application is the integral form.

Comment: Assume ρ= 1/50 then if I say E=10^11/5 x 8.85418782 by using ρ/ϵ0=1/50 x 8.85418782 × 10^-12 would it be wrong?

Comment: $\rho=\frac{1}{50}$ is a nonsensical statement. A charge distribution has units (and a location!)

Comment: If the charges on the plate are uniformly distributed would the location be necessary? And sorry ρ=1/50 C/cm. So with these correction how accurate is the answer I found?

Comment: @FarStar Charges uniformly distributed are a very special case (a simplification). Using the integral form, it helps to have an objective view of the problem, and is physically more correct. Even then it is simplified with assumptions such as the charge is uniformly distributed.

Comment: @FarStar If you start from the differential form or the integral form, you'll get the same result, for this particular case, the load evenly distributed. So your numerical calculation maybe is correct. But do not forget that you work with a simplified model.

If for example, you want to analyze a case containing media with different characteristics ($\varepsilon$, $\mu$), the differential form is not for you, as there are points of discontinuity on the boundary of the media.

Comment: Okay, I start to get it now. Thanks for your help and I just want to ask one more thing. Pardon me if it is a dumb question. Shouldn't ∬SD∙ds be equal to D-field flux?

Comment: @FarStar In the SI system of units, D is the Electric Flux Density; the surface integral is the Electrical Flux, which is equal to the charge enclosed by the surface. In the SI system, Electric Flux and Electric Charge, are measured in *Coulombs*

There are no dumb question, so ask with confidence!